# How to catch a NullPointerException for particular member variables of a java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I have a method called `register` which takes a custom class (called `RegistrationRequest`) as a parameter and there are a few variables in `RegistrationRequest` which are required and cannot be null (`url` and `type`). The `register` method saves the registration in DynamoDB. However, I want to catch a custom exception if either of the 2 required variables are null and avoid saving such entries in DynamoDB. The code block for this method is somewhat like this

```
public Registration register(RegistrationRequest registration)
var dbEntry = RegistrationImpl.builder()
            .withType(registration.getType())
            .withDescription(registration.getDescription())
            .withUrl(registration.getUrl())
            .withCategory(registration.getCategory())
            .withMaxDuration(registration.getMaxDuration())
            .build();
    try {
      return repository.save(dbEntry);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      ......
    }
```

I want to have another catch block which checks that `registration.type` and `registration.url` are not null and if they are, then catch that and throw an exception and therefore prevent saving such entries in DynamoDB. How do I do that?

Comment: Does your db/repository have constraints that will throw error if url and type is null? Also, theres something wrong with your understanding of catch blocks. They dont _check_ if something is null or not. They just catch the exception if it happens within the try {}

Answer (score 4):

### Builder throws exception on null-check

Your `withType` and `withUrl` methods should check for a null in their passed argument. That is the job of a Builder, to gather and verify inputs before instantiating the principal class.

A convenient way to throw the [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)).

```
RegistrationImpl withType ( final Type type ) 
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( type , "Your exception message goes here." ) ;
    this.type = type ;
    return this ;
}
```

### *Jakarta Validation* in your data carrier

Additionally, your data carrier, the `RegistrationRequest` class, should validate its data fields to disallow incorrect data.

You may find handy the use of [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) (formerly *Bean Validation*) to assist you in validating those data fields.

Currently the only implementation of that specification is [*Hibernate Validator*](https://hibernate.org/validator/). You may want to skip the Jakarta API, and address Hibernate Validator directly.

Answer (score 0):

The validation can be performed just when you enter the method. Something like this:

```
public Registration register(RegistrationRequest registration)
    if (registration.getType() == null || registration.getUrl() == null) {
        throw new CustomIllegalArgumentException(); // Or just log the error you want
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do like this

```
public Registration register(RegistrationRequest registration) {
    if(registration.getType()!=null&&registration.getUrl()!=null){
        var dbEntry = RegistrationImpl.builder()
                .withType(registration.getType())
                .withDescription(registration.getDescription())
                .withUrl(registration.getUrl())
                .withCategory(registration.getCategory())
                .withMaxDuration(registration.getMaxDuration())
                .build();
        try {
            return repository.save(dbEntry);
        }catch (Exception e){
            ...
        }
    }else{
        //you can return null or throw runtime exception here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by adding a custom check before attempting to save the entry in the DynamoDB repository. If either `registration.getType()` or `registration.getUrl()` is null, you can throw a custom exception. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
public Registration register(RegistrationRequest registration) {
    // Check for null values in required fields
    if (registration.getType() == null || registration.getUrl() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type and URL cannot be null");
    }

    // If all required fields are not null, proceed with creating the entry
    var dbEntry = RegistrationImpl.builder()
            .withType(registration.getType())
            .withDescription(registration.getDescription())
            .withUrl(registration.getUrl())
            .withCategory(registration.getCategory())
            .withMaxDuration(registration.getMaxDuration())
            .build();

    try {
        // Attempt to save the entry in DynamoDB repository
        return repository.save(dbEntry);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any exceptions that occur during saving
        // You can log the error or perform any necessary actions here
        // Example: logger.error("Failed to save registration entry", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save registration entry", e);
    }
}
```

With this modification, if either `registration.getType()` or `registration.getUrl()` is null, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown, preventing the entry from being saved in DynamoDB. Otherwise, if there's any other exception during the saving process, it will be caught and rethrown as a `RuntimeException`.